# Navbar items don't align on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

`justify-content`,`mr-auto`, editing via css and etc doesn't work and items don't align
Here's my code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light shadow">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="navbar-text">Политех
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://agpk.kz"> Вернуться на сайт </a>
        </li>
    <li class="nav-item">   
    <a class="nav-link" href"/login"> Войти </a>
    </li>
</ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want to have your `<li>` centered in the middle of your navbar?
If it's the case, you can turn it into a `d-flex` with a width of 100% of the parent element and align it with `justify-content-`:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-flex justify-content-center w-100">
```